# Is it true that POST can be used instead of GET in all scenarios?

Tags: http, post, get, httprequest

I've read lots of articles about the differences between GET and POST. Lots of them are available here at StackOverflow.

A summary of the important differences is:

- Post can send its information via body while GET should not (but I think it can be done practically)
- Some browsers cache the GET results and rely on the idempotent behavior of GET requests.
- Using GET is much easier than using POST for most of developers.

Concluding this summary, Using GET in POST situations is bad and dangerous.
But is it true that ignoring the easiness, POST can be used as a replacement of the GET requests as it seems it totally covers the GET requirements.

To clarify that I'm not crazy!, I'm not going to use POST instead of GET. This question is just about to check if I understand the GET and POST difference correctly.

Comment: GETting something implies fetching/pulling (towards you). POSTing something implies pushing (away from you) So from that alone, it should be clear that these are different things with different semantics. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: @Gordon You're right. My problem is that is there any constrained logic bound to these verbs? For example I was wondering to use a custom TAKE keyword on my ajax requests and on the server side act like a GET to such requests. What happens if so?

Comment: Yes, there is constrained logic. See the link posted. They have different semantics which they should adhere to, like GET should be safe from side effects. The user should be able to rely on getting the same result whenever retrieving a resource through it. POST is not. And when creating a new resource through it, the response should be different, e.g. resource representation returned, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, POST is not a replacement of GET requests. There are two important things that a POST request cannot do that a GET request can.

1. You cannot generate a POST request simply by typing a URL in the address bar of the browser. This always generates a GET request.
2. You cannot generate a POST requesting using an ordinary link in HTML. This has far-reaching consequences. You cannot find a page that is only accessible using a POST request with any search engine, and you cannot link to it unless it is done by an HTML form or using Javascript.

Comment: I'm developing SPA applications. In that case there is no link on the page. Everything is just a routing or binding click events of elements via JavaScript. Is it true that it's possible to to such in case of SPA?

Comment: Yeah, in single page applications, developers often successfully use only POST requests. It causes fewer headaches related to possible caching by the browser, and you don't have to decide what to use for each request. OTOH, sometimes you want the benefits of browser caching.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good practice that you classify your transaction.  These methods are very important specially when you are developing an API Service Oriented architecture or even Single Page Applications.

GET - used to retrieve a dataset. (also has a limitation for url length. parameters are exposed and urlencoded.)
POST - Saving/adding (this is more secure)

EX:

```
GET /items - means you are getting the list of items. 
POST /items - means you are saving/adding item(s)
```

and later you might need to learn PUT and DELETE too.

But for now, always use POST in your form or ajax request when saving/adding data. and GET when retrieving data.